# What does "_$vdhHitId is not defined" error refer to?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the following Javascript error appearing in the Google Chrome debugger.

[image]

This doesn't appear on a regular, consistent, basis and it doesn't appear to impact the normal operation of the page. I've never seen this before and am curious if anyone knows what this is referring to? This is not coming from any of my code, or any library I'm using, as far as I know.

A Google search on this returns nothing that I could find.

Comment: Maybe Is a Chrome extension...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@SimonNigro is correct. In my case it was extension "Video DownloadHelper"
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-downloadhelper/lmjnegcaeklhafolokijcfjliaokphfk. An error disappeared after I disabled the extension.